# Run class objects in different processes python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

1. I am writing a code where I want to run a function every n sec.
2. Create different class objects to to call this function.
3. I want to run these objects in different processes.

My code is something like this:

```
class MTR:
     def __init__(self, serverIP, destinationIP):
         self.serverIP= serverIP
         self.destinationIP= destinationIP
     def get_mtr_result(self):
         #ssh to server IP and run mtr to destination ip
     def recur_code(self):
        threading.Timer(5.0, self.recur_code).start()
        #get the output from get_mtr_result() and write it to a file every 5 sec
if __name__== "__main__":
    pool_size= 5
    pool= Pool(pool_size)
    serverIPList= ["1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2", "3.3.3.3"]
    objects= [MTR(server_ip, destination_ip) for server_ip in serverIPList]
    for obj in objects:
      pool.apply_async(obj.recur_code, ())
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The code works perfectly but it stops automatically. I do not want the code to stop unless there is a keyboard interruption. I am assuming this is something to do with the for loop and pool.close() but I cannot figure it out. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: put pool.join() **before** pool.close()

Comment: This throws "assert self._state in (CLOSE, TERMINATE)" error.